# Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::update() must be an array

Tags: zend-db, zend-db-table

I am having some trouble updating a row.

My class is extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Here is my code:

```
return $this->update(
            array('data' => $data),
            $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id = ?", $id)
        ) ? true : false;
```

The exception I keep getting is:
`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::update() must be an array, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/library/Session/Handler.php on line 51 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/libraries/zend-framework/ZendFramework-1.11.3-minimal/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 587`

I tried passing it an array also but nothing happens. Any idea?!

Answer (score 0):

You may use array in second argument of ->update()

example:

```
 $this->update(
    array('data' => $data),
    array("id = ?" => $id),
 ) ? true : false;
```

but the string must be ok

becouse

```
/**
 * Convert an array, string, or Zend_Db_Expr object
 * into a string to put in a WHERE clause.
 *
 * @param mixed $where
 * @return string
 */
protected function _whereExpr($where)
{
    if (empty($where)) {
        return $where;
    }
    **if (!is_array($where)) {**
        $where = array($where);
    }
```